# How to create a secure PHP REST API using OAuth?

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth

i want to create a web app with REST API service. i want it to be like Facebook API.i know Facebook uses OAuth.
so how can i create a PHP REST API using OAuth?
Thanks

Comment: have you read any documentation? this quesiton is a bit generalized... maybe start with http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ServerHowTo